# Using Azure AD Authentication Results in Error Handling Remote Login

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor application.  Sometimes, I get the following exception when the application redirects to /signin-oidc when I'm not authenticated after signing out:

```
OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'access_denied', error_description: 'AADSTS50105: The signed in user '{EmailHidden}' is not assigned to a role for the application '<myClientApplicationID>'
```

I have a feeling like it could be trying to automatically use a different Azure AD account since I have several AD accounts for various, unrelated, clients. The URL that triggers this issue is `https://localhost:5000/signin-oidc` and prevents me from logging in using my Azure AD account.  This does not happen all the time, but when it does, I don't know how to trigger the standard Microsoft login screen so that I can sign in using my valid credentials.  If this is true, then I wonder if there is a way to prevent it from attempting to use any account other than the ones that configured for the tenant.

How can this exception be handled/configured so that it will force the user to login using their Azure AD account?  Below you will find the startup code for authentication.

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

And here are the options in my appsettings.json

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mydomain.org",
    "TenantId": "<myTenantId>",
    "ClientId": "<myClientId>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps to assign application roles to your users.

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

3.
[image]

4.when you click 'Select', then click on the 'assign' in the lower left corner, and you'll see that the assignment has been completed.

[image]

For more information, please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-sign-in-problem-federated-sso-gallery#user-not-assigned-a-role).

Comment: I have assigned users to roles, so I don't think that is the issue.  I have figured out that I need to sign out of all AD accounts across all organizations before it will present the standard sign-in dialog at which point I can specify the username that has access to the application.  This tells me that it was using another account when this occurs.